# Show Removed Posts not working properly on Reputation History

Tags: bug, profile-page, reputation-history

With [image] like so, I see:

[image]

With [image] like so, I see:

[image]

With [image], I shouldn't see:

```
+1   removed    How to instruct cron to execute a job every second week?
-1   downvoted  How to instruct cron to execute a job every second week?
```

Refreshing the page and toggling the checkbox make no difference.

Comment: Are you seeing `+1 removed` without checking show removed posts?

Comment: @hims056 Yes, as you can see from the first screenshot.

Comment: May be for you. But no reproduced from me. I don't see `+1 removed` if I uncheck show removed posts option.

Comment: @hims056 Exactly! This is the first time I've seen this... I think the only way this could be reproduced is for an admin to *Login As* me.